# Как в Android создать и вывести bitmap на виджет view?

Tags: android, java, canvas

Здравствуйте. Решил написать программу для Android на Java.
Возникла проблема, требуется на слое (layuot) с виджетами (например с двумя кнопками), нарисовать изображение, которое при клике на нём перемещалось в место клика, никак не могу придумать как организовать это. 
Копаю в сторону обьекта view, набросал уже следующий код:

```
 public void onResume(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(100, 100, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas c = new Canvas(b);
        c.drawBitmap(b, 10, 10, null);
        view1 = (View)findViewById(R.id.view1);
        view1.draw(c);
    }
```

Код работает, но изображение не появляется,  хотя и появляться по сути нечему.
Заранее спасибо!

Comment: А причём тут виджеты?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы можете перекрыть метод onDraw вашего вида и рисовать на Canvas в нем. Примерно, так:

```
public class SomeView extends View{
    // TODO: Дополнительный код: конструкторы и тд.

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas over = new Canvas(bitmap);

        // TODO: рисовать на over

        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, null);
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, переработал код:
http://pastebin.com/iixupMXv
Вызываю код вот так:
http://pastebin.com/e29R9x04
Но он не опять не выводит картинку, но уже в SurfaceView . Как заставить его делать это?